# Problem tracking custom error with Application Insights: TypeError: Cannot read property 'stack' of undefined

Tags: node.js, error-handling, azure-application-insights

I have written a custom error class and would like to track the error using Azure Application Insights. I am using Node.js. When I try tracking the custom error I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'stack' of undefined
    at Function.EnvelopeFactory.createExceptionData (/Users/liam/Desktop/CustomError/node_modules/applicationinsights/out/Library/EnvelopeFactory.js:145:40)
    at Function.EnvelopeFactory.createEnvelope (/Users/liam/Desktop/CustomError/node_modules/applicationinsights/out/Library/EnvelopeFactory.js:32:40)
    at NodeClient.TelemetryClient.track (/Users/liam/Desktop/CustomError/node_modules/applicationinsights/out/Library/TelemetryClient.js:116:44)
    at NodeClient.TelemetryClient.trackException (/Users/liam/Desktop/CustomError/node_modules/applicationinsights/out/Library/TelemetryClient.js:69:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/liam/Desktop/CustomError/app.js:10:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
```

Here is the code:

```
class CustomError extends Error {  
    constructor (message) {
      super(message)
      
      Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
      this.name = this.constructor.name;
      this.status = 404;
    }
  
    statusCode() {
      return this.status
    }
}

const appInsights = require('applicationinsights');
appInsights.setup('MY_KEY').start();
let client = appInsights.defaultClient;

const customError = require('./exceptions');
let newError = new customError('The custom error was thrown')

client.trackException(newError);
```

I have done some research into TelemetryClient objects based on other resources online but I don't think that is the right direction.

I am using this resource as a guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics#trackexception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by passing in a key value pair to trackException where the key is exception and the value is the error:

```
client.trackException({exception: new customError('This is a custom error')});
```

Full code:

```
class CustomError extends Error {  
    constructor (message) {
      super(message)
      
      Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
      this.name = this.constructor.name;
      this.status = 404;
    }
  
    statusCode() {
      return this.status
    }
}

const appInsights = require('applicationinsights');
appInsights.setup('MY_KEY').start();
let client = appInsights.defaultClient;

client.trackException({exception: new CustomError('This is a custom error')});
```